# Is the question "did you request for the bill" correct?

Tags: phrase-requests

Really confused here and can't find anything online. I think the correct usage will be "did you request the bill", but not sure if "did you request for the bill" is correct too?

Comment: Why do you think you need to add the _for_?

Comment: _Request_ (as a verb) means _ask for_, so, no, it isn't correct.

Answer (score 4):

The word *request* can be either a noun or a verb.  The verb *to request* is transitive and so has a direct object.  So you say:

> I am going to my boss to **request** compassionate leave

Alternatively you can use the noun and say

> I am going to put in  **a request for** compassionate leave.

Where there might be a confusion is that of you replace the word *request* with the word *ask*, then you do have to use the preposition *for* and say:

> I am going to my boss to **ask for** compassionate leave.

It is true that even the word *ask* can sometimes (in a strictly limited and idiomatic context) be use as a noun.

> You want me to look after your pet python for the entire month you are on holiday?  That's a huge ask.

But you would not talk about putting in *an ask for compassionate leave* to your boss.  It would be correctly understood but mark you out not a fluent speaker of the language.

Comment: +1. Nicely explained.

Comment: -1 Answer to a bad question.